# How do Berzerk and Shaken interact?

Tags: combat, savage-worlds, shaken

If a character with the Berzerk edge takes damage and goes berzerk, they cannot perform any actions that require concentration.  Is the Spirit test to recover from being Shaken considered to be a task requiring concentration.

The rules seem to indicate the Spirit test is automatic, so I'm of the mind it doesn't require concentration.

What's the official ruling on this?

Comment: See this meta post -http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/shaken-tag-for-savage-worlds - for discussion about the Shaken tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Berserk characters recover from Shaken like everyone else does.

http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=195974

Comment: Thanks for that link, but that doesn't actually cover my question.  However, I'll be using that forum more often.  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I received a [definitive answer](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36945) from the forum [Joe Bedurndurn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/15327/2261) suggested.

> The actual text of the Edge is "The warrior ignores all wound modifiers while Berserk, but cannot use any skills, Edges, or maneuvers that require concentration, including Shooting and Taunt, but not Intimidation."
>
> The free attempt to recover from being Shaken is not the use of a skill, Edge, or maneuver of any sort, so it's not covered. You can attempt to recover from Shaken completely normally while berserk.

Comment: Could you share a link?

Comment: Link added above.  I couldn't access it at work at the time.

Answer (score 1):

In the Deluxe Edition RAW, there's no text specific to that. It does say that a character only goes Berserk if she fails a Smarts test.

From the Deluxe Edition:

- **Smarts** is a measure of how well your character knows his world and culture, how well he thinks on his feet, and mental agility.
- **Spirit** reflects inner wisdom and willpower. Spirit is very important as it helps your character recover from being Shaken.

I'd rule that Smarts tests are the only attribute tests that require concentration. Spirit, being more of a instictive/gut feeling kind of attribute, reflect your character's morals and will and as such doesn't require concentration.

That's not to say Spirit based skills don't require concentration - each action should be ruled by the GM based on common sense - hence the deliberately vague rules on the matter.

Comment: I like that as a rule of thumb, but I don't see that working for *Persuasion* or *Intimidation* (a Berserker would just hit them and not stop.)  Also, the RAW states *Shooting* requires enough concentration to be banned by Berserk.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I meant when doing a trait test. A skill test is something else entirely.
I believe the official ruling is "it's up to the GM" as the rules are deliberately vague.

Comment: Do you mean "attribute test"?  Skill tests and attribute tests are both trait tests.  From **Chapter One: Character Creation, Traits**: "Characters are defined by attributes and skills, collectievly called "Traits"."  And yes, I agree that it's really something that falls to the GM.  :-)

Comment: Doh! :facepalm: Yes, that's what I meant. I'm editing it up.

Comment: I made an error as well.  The RAW states *Intimidation* can be used while berserk.